# Find the arithmetic mean of all three digit numbers whose rightmost digit is twice of left most digit - Concept of average of averages

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, average

I was able to solve it by listing all the cases from :-

1. 102, 112, ..., 192
2. 204, 214, ..., 294
3. 306, 316,..., 396
4. 408, 418, ..., 498

I added all the 4 AP series and then divided by total 40 terms to arrive at average

---

However in the book, there was a method given which seems more efficient but I am not able to understand that:-

In that the author took average of each series separately like :-

1. average of 1st series - 147
2. average of 2nd series - 249
3. average of 3rd series - 351
4. average of 4th series - 453

and then found out the average of these 4 terms

I am not aware of this method of finding out averages, please help me understand this method

Comment: This only works because each of the sets has the same number of elements. In this case, to find the average of all the numbers, it suffices to take the average of the averages of each of the sets.

In general, if the sets have different sizes, this will result in an incorrect answer.

Comment: Ohh okay, thank you :)

Comment: Right, this only works for sets of the same size. In general, you need a weighted average.

Comment: So $$\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_{40}}{40}=\frac{\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_{10}}{10}+\cdots+\frac{a_{31}+\cdots +a_{40}}{10}}{4}$$